# How to input the same strings after 7 objects

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on my code as I am generating the list of ids that start from `361` to `375` so I can input the strings in the button objects. I would like to input the two same strings in the 2 different button objects using with two different ids.

Here is for example:

```
>>> 361 >>>> 101 BBC One South East
>>> 362 >>>> 102 BBC Two
>>> 363 >>>> 103 ITV
>>> 364 >>>> 104 Channel 4
>>> 365 >>>> 105 Channel 5
>>> 366 >>>> 106 Sky One
>>> 367 >>>> 107 Sky Living
>>> 368 >>>> 101 BBC One South East
>>> 369 >>>> 102 BBC Two
>>> 370 >>>> 103 ITV
>>> 371 >>>> 104 Channel 4
>>> 372 >>>> 105 Channel 5
>>> 373 >>>> 106 Sky One
>>> 374 >>>> 107 Sky Living
```

Here is the code:

```
channel_index = 0

#set the channels text in the label
for program_id in range(361, 375):
    self.parent.getControl(int(program_id)).setLabel(channels_list[channel_index])
    channel_index += 1
```

Here is the list for `channels_list`:

```
['102 BBC Two', '103 ITV', '104 Channel 4', '105 Channel 5', '106 Sky One', '107 Sky Living', '108 Sky Atlantic']
```

What the code will do is they will only input the 7 strings in 7 buttons so it will not input the same string over the next 7 buttons as it will give me an error: IndexError: list index out of range.

What I am expecting to do is to input the strings in the first 7 buttons so in the next 7 buttons, I want to input the same strings. Can you please show me how I could do that using with my current code?

**EDIT: When I try this:**

```
for program_id in range(361, 375):
    print channels_list[channel_index]
```

It will give me the output for the `channels_list`:

```
102 BBC Two
103 ITV
104 Channel 4
105 Channel 5
106 Sky One
107 Sky Living
108 Sky Atlantic
```

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
102 BBC Two
103 ITV
104 Channel 4
105 Channel 5
106 Sky One
107 Sky Living
108 Sky Atlantic
102 BBC Two
103 ITV
104 Channel 4
105 Channel 5
106 Sky One
107 Sky Living
108 Sky Atlantic
```

Here is what I use to store the channels in the list:

```
for channels in self.channel:
    if(channel == channels or len(channels_list)) > 0:  #check to see if it equals any or we already found it
       channels_list.append(channels)  #add chanel to list

       if len(channels_list) == 7:
          break
```

Comment: It's a little confuse... What is the final output you are specting? Based on what input?

Comment: @DamianLattenero I have updated it, please see in my update question.

Comment: [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just want to add the button to the list twice?

```
for channels in self.channel:
    if(channel == channels or len(channels_list)) > 0:  #check to see if it equals any or we already found it
       channels_list.append(channels)  #add channel to list
       channels_list.append(channels)  #add channel to list again
```

Or add it in sequence? Then rewrite the for loop or have a for loop outside the for loop and have it run twice:

```
for i in range(2): # loops twice
    for channels in self.channel:
        if(channel == channels or len(channels_list)) > 0:  #check to see if it equals any or we already found it
           channels_list.append(channels)  #add channel to list
```

Comment: that's an option, yes, plus one here

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your question, you just have to start over after get the index 7, like this:

```
channels_list = ['102 BBC Two', '103 ITV', '104 Channel 4', '105 Channel 5', '106 Sky One', '107 Sky Living', '108 Sky Atlantic']

channel_index = 0

#set the channels text in the label
for program_id in range(361, 375):
    print(channels_list[channel_index])
    channel_index += 1
    if(channel_index == 7):
      channel_index = 0
```

the output will be:

```
102 BBC Two
103 ITV
104 Channel 4
105 Channel 5
106 Sky One
107 Sky Living
108 Sky Atlantic
102 BBC Two
103 ITV
104 Channel 4
105 Channel 5
106 Sky One
107 Sky Living
108 Sky Atlantic
```